# Can I create a bootable live disk for Linux Mint using a non-optical external hard drive?

Tags: linux-mint, bootable

Is it possible for me to create a bootable live disk for Linux Mint (or any distro of Linux in general) using a Seagate 1 TB hard disk? If so, how? Will the image be permanently burnt to the disk if I do so?
Edit: Thank you! However, how do I make a full install (without using dd)? Will the windows burn to disc tool work ?

Answer (score 0):

In general: Yes.

There are two options you may apply:

1. Create an installation medium

Ususally done by writing an install iso to a medium, this might be a CD, a USB drive, or an SD-Card. No limitations. This includes your 1 TB drive.

Depending on the distribution, this will offer booting into a live version (next to installing the OS), e.g. as MINT does. These live versions are not meant as permanent operating systems, but are running in RAM only. So installed programs, downloaded data etc. are not stored (except for when you accesses the actual drives of the computer you are using).

2. Make a full install on a medium

This only applies to media that allow rewriting data, so usually CDs are out of the picture. However USB-drives or SD cards are fine. The mode is quite simple: The USB drive is what your hard drive on the PC would be, so changes, installed programs and so on are permanently stored on this medium and whenever you boot from this medium, the last state and data are available.

---

Note that in both cases you may as well still partition the drive so that you have both the install medium / full install AND a standard external drive available. A 1TB external disk might need to server more purposes than just a live version of linux.

Comment: You have to be very careful what tools your use. Most now use dd and create what is called a hybrid DVD/flash drive installer. It assumes a smaller flash drive. And the dd totally erases the first 2+ GB of the drive (the size of ISO). And that erases the partition table making rest of drive unusable. I prefer to put a full install on every drive, but then have larger flash drives and now a couple of external SSD that also boot ISO using grub.  Best to always have a current flash drive for repair/recovery of every install you have both Windows & Linux.